# @font-face работает на локале и не работает на сервере, что может быть не так ?

Tags: шрифты, css

Подключение шрифта

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: "OpenSans light";
      src: url('../fonts/Open_Sans/opensans_lt.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/Open_Sans/opensans_lt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Open_Sans/opensans_lt.woff') format('woff'),            url('../fonts/Open_Sans/opensans_lt.ttf') format('truetype'),    url('../fonts/Open_Sans/opensans_lt.svg') format('svg');
  }

.titles h3 {
  font-family: "OpenSans light", Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.3125em;
  line-height: 1.14286em;
}
```

На локальном сервере отображается шрифт *OpenSans light*, а когда заливаешь на хостинг *Arial*. Причем, помимо этого шрифта еще фонт фейсом добавляю 3 других, и все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нашел ответ, надо было дать другое имя шрифту